# How do I deal with poison in Shipwrecked?

Tags: dont-starve, dont-starve-shipwrecked

Poor wickerbottom got [Shipwrecked](https://www.kleientertainment.com/games/dont-starve/shipwrecked). She cut down a tree and got bit by a green snake.

There's green bubbles at my healthmeter, and every so often the screen flashes green and I lose HP.

How do I cure myself of the poison?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To cure the effects of poison you need to consume
[Anti Venom](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Anti_Venom):

> Anti Venom is an item from Don't starve Shipwrecked. It is used to remove the Poison debuff.
> Crafting an Anti Venom requires 1 Venom Gland, 3 Seaweed, and 2 Coral. It is a single use item.

It is said that [Snake Oil](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Snake_Oil) will, in due time when it gets a function, also cure poison.

> Snake Oil is a very rare drop from normal Snakes and Poison Snakes.
>
> It (currently) has no functionality or effect.
>
> It is presumed to be an alternative to antivenom when it gets a function.

Comment: I for one hope they keep snake oil useless, in reference to [Snake Oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_oil)

Comment: Since the update, consuming "venom" itself works as well, but it'll cost some HP.

Answer (score 1):

The other way to be cured of poison is simply to *wait*. Poison simply wears off after 3 days. Unfortunately, it gets *worse* before it wears off, starting at 1 damage every 10 seconds for the first day, increasing until it's doing 4 damage every 5 seconds for the last tenth of the third day.

The [damage chart](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Poison) is in the wiki, but the practical upshot is that 3 days is 24 real-time minutes, and you'll take 48 damage the first day, 78 damage the second day, and 109 damage the third day. Either you use some [Anti Venom](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Anti_Venom), or you heal 235 damage over three days. I highly recommend Anti Venom (and/or wearing a Seashell Suit or Horned Helmet to prevent receiving Poison from physical damage in the first place), but if you can't find the ingredients, a reliable source of healing can work as a replacement.